# Is there a Job board to post quote requests?

Tags: wordpress

Can we post requests for quotes on this forum? Or should we just directly contact the FIND AN EXPERT on the civicrm.org site?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can contact the experts. You can also post in chat at https://chat.civicrm.org.

There is https://civicrm.org/jobs - it seems more intended for hiring staff but there's a choice on the job form for "project-based".